# Position Element in dependence of another elements width

Tags: html, css, angular, button

I have an element (a button) and I want to position it below the bottom right corner of a textarea (there is also some more stuff on the right of the textarea. Since the width of that textarea is dependent upon the display size, I want to somehow set the left margin of that button in dependence of the width of the text area. Is that even a possible solution? I'm also using Angular 9.

I hope someone can help me.

This is the html:

```
<div class="user-container">
<div class="editor">
    <h3>Berichte oder schreibe etwas über deinen Tag</h3>
    <ckeditor 
        [editor]="Editor" 
        [(ngModel)]="editorData" 
        (ready)="onReady($event)"></ckeditor>
</div>
<div class="date-picker">
    <h3>Wähle das Datum</h3>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Wähle das Datum</mat-label>
        <input matInput (dateInput)="onDateChange($event.value)" [matDatepicker]="picker" [ngModel]="date" (click)="picker.open()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<app-emoji-rating-scale (emojiSelected)="onEmojiSelected($event)"></app-

emoji-rating-scale>
</div>
<button (click)="onSaveEntry(editorData)" mat-raised-button>Eintrag speichern</button>
<button class="calendar-button" routerLink="/calendar" mat-raised-button>Einträge anzeigen</button>
```

And this the css (if it helps):

```
h3 {
font-weight: 500;
}

.user-container {
    position: relative;
    height:75vh;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.editor {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
    height:70%;
}

.editor h3 {
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.date-picker {
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

:host ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable_inline {
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid var(--ck-color-toolbar-border);
}

app-emoji-rating-scale {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Kind regards
Fonzane

Comment: Please provide some `html` and `css` to your question too ;)

Comment: sure, here you go (sorry for not providing it immediately. Just didn't think it would be neccessary.